# Switching from activity to another manifest file problem?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-intent

I'm getting an error when i click my link in my first activity(Explorer), i would like it to bring up the file picker i have created (AndroidExplorer) Is there something wrong with my code activity code or my manifest.

Any help would be appreciated

Explorer Class

```
public class Explorer extends Activity{


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button picture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.picture);

    picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Explorer.this, AndroidExplorer.class);
          startActivity(intent);
          finish();
        }

      });
    }
}
```

AndroidExplorer class

```
public class AndroidExplorer extends ListActivity {

private List<String> item = null;
private List<String> path = null;
private String root="/sdcard/DCIM/camera/";
private TextView myPath;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);
    getDir(root);
}

private void getDir(String dirPath)
{
    myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);

    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();

    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if(!dirPath.equals(root))
    {

        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);

        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());

    }

    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
            File file = files[i];
            path.add(file.getPath());
            if(file.isDirectory())
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            else
                item.add(file.getName());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    File file = new File(path.get(position));

    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        if(file.canRead())
            getDir(path.get(position));
        else
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    }).show();
    }
}}
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.Explorer"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Explorer"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity android:name=".AndroidExplorer"
        android:label="Screen 2 - New actvity.">

    </activity>
</application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Please can you provide the logcat output of the error?

Comment: The element type "activity" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</activity>". 

and

Attribute name "activity" associated with an element type "application" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Comment: I am a retard... The answer is make sure your phone emulator has an SD card in...

Answer (score 1):

Well, seeing as your root variable is a path to the sdcard, it seems that the directory won't exist if you don't have an SD card plugged in. I think you should probably trap that error and throw a pop-up window or something to let the user know an SD card is needed.